# Android Studio: Choosing app directory with setConfig() method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to find my application's path after its installation and initializing a XML file as a config file by giving its path in app/config directory.

I made lots of research here but could not solve my problem:
The config file is not initialized/recognized/seen by the application.
The error is always about not loading the config.

I have tried many ways to get path but the result did not change. 
Related part of my code is :

```
            Context context = new Context();
            PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
            String s = getPackageName();
            PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
            s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
            s +=  "/app/config/xmlsignature-config.xml";
            context.setConfig(new Config(s));
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: `Context context = new Context();`. Compiler error: Cannot instantiate the type Context.

Comment: No, it is not giving compiler error. I'm even building APK and running it until this step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
The path that I found was true but there were no **app** file or **config** file in /data/data directory as I looked from **DDMS** ( can be found by opening Android Device Monitor tab). 
Then I **moved** my *xmlsignature_config.xml* file to **app/src/res/row** directory.

Then instead of:

```
    Context context = new Context();
    PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
    String s = getPackageName();
    PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
    s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
    s +=  "/app/config/xmlsignature-config.xml";
    context.setConfig(new Config(s));
```

I have written

```
    Context context = new Context();
    Config(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xmlsignature_config)));
```

After this change, the program reached to my xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't instantiate your context. That's created by Android for you.

You should change:

```
Context context = new Context();
```

to: `Context context = getContext();` or `Context context = getApplicationContext();`

Comment: Actually, the context class that I used belongs a specific library. Thus, it does not accept getContext() or getApplicationContext() methods.